# Issue with Rally custom list with deep export (bug)

Tags: rally

I am using Rally "Custom list With Deep export"
We have a field Planned end date. How ever while exporting it gives the result for next day in CSV format.

e.g: If the date is 31 December 2019 in Rally then in CSV it shows as 1 January 2020. Is it intended behavior? or a bug

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, is this related to the timezone that you are in? If your workspace timezone is different from your machine timezone, it can throw up oddities like this.

The app might not be timezone aware.